# What is the concept of service master key in FCI?

Tags: sql-server, clustering, sql-server-2019, encryption, service-master-key

In a single sql server instances, sensitive data like passwords in linked server and credentials are encrypted using the server master key.

The key or objects can be decrypted only by the sql service account or the local computer account.

However, in a FCI, on node 1 suppose I use the service account as domain/user1 and on node 2 suppose I use account domain/user2; then when there is a failover to node 2, then how will node 2 be able to access the key or decrypt the objects encrypted by the key?

Comment: It would not be a good practice to use different accounts to run the SQL service on different nodes of the FCI.  You’d be introducing unneeded complexity, with no benefit. What would you be trying to accomplish by doing so?

Comment: I'm just wondering whether there is any documentation to advise to not do so. I'm thinking and learning really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one instance in an FCI, so only one SMK.  When the instance restarts on another node, it uses the same service account, and so is able to decrypt the SMK.

There's an informative thread [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9514616d-173f-40df-9dee-fef6de82b273/cluster-failover-forced-service-master-key-regeneration-consequences?forum=sqlsecurity) with answers from [Lauentiu Cristofor](https://www.linkedin.com/in/laurentiu-cristofor/) from the SQL Server security dev team.

Comment: So the admin must make sure that the service account on node 1 and node 2 are the same?

Comment: Yes and it should be a Group Managed Service Account. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/group-managed-service-accounts/group-managed-service-accounts-overview